# How do I thoroughly check bad sectors of a HDD connected over USB (in Raspbian)

Tags: raspbian, external-hdd

I have a RaspberryPi 1 Model B and a, running Raspbian Wheezy. I recently bought a new hard disk - [Western Digital WD10JPVX](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C9TEBJQ). I want to thoroughly check its health status, bad sectors if any. So I have [Anker USB enclosure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00H98AXOE) and a [powered USB3 hub](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005D69QD8) and I can connect the HDD to Pi.

So how do I run tests? Which app/tool I can use? I wouldn't mind if it takes hours for diagnosis.

Answer (score 3):

The usual tool for this is `badblocks`, which is part of [E2fsprogs](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/). If your drive has never been used before, you could run a destructive test with something like

```
badblocks -w -s /dev/sdb
```

(assuming your drive shows up as `/dev/sdb`). `-w` enables destructive write tests, and `-s` displays progress information.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a drive might pass `badblocks -w` despite "soft errors".  After running badblocks, you should check `dmesg` for retry warnings, and `smartctl -a -d /dev/...` to see if the drive discovered bad sectors and managed to hide them.  You don't want to see any smart failures, and the raw value of `Reallocated_Sector_Ct` should be zero.  (Same for Current_Pending_Sector, though I have no idea how that would be non-zero without badblocks showing a bad sector).

https://lime-technology.com/forum/index.php?topic=23792.msg210208#msg210208

https://lime-technology.com/forum/index.php?topic=23792.msg210176#msg210176

---

That last point is true for hard disk drives.  It would be hard to say anything so confident for solid state drives, though it's probably worth looking to see if there's a SMART counter that estimates the drive rated wear percentage.

Also for SSDs you would want to increase the test size to something like 4Mb.  (`badblocks -w -b 4096 -c 1024`).  Forcing 1024-byte writes across the entire drive is not going to have good effects on the lifetime of an SSD... I don't know if there's a better technique for burn-in tests of SSDs.

Nowadays you should always use a minimum block size (`-b`) of 4096.